# REPLACE query working in SQL but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I made the following query:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT image_first, REPLACE(image_first,'/home/erik/','')   
     FROM reviews_media WHERE review_id = $id");
```

I've tested it in PhpMyAdmin and it's working. But when I echo it, it's still showing the `/home/erik/` part.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvioulsy you echo `image_first` value, but you need to echo result of `REPLACE`. You can modify query as:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT image_first, REPLACE(image_first,'/home/erik/','') as new_img FROM reviews_media WHERE review_id = $id");
```

See, I added an alias to result of `REPLACE` function. Now you can echo something like:

```
echo $row['new_img'];
```

As you don't do anything to result of `REPLACE` in a query, you can also simplify it and do a replace with php:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT image_first FROM reviews_media WHERE review_id = $id");
// fetching results
echo str_replace('/home/erik/', '', $row['image_first']);
```

Comment: If answer solves your problem - feel free to accept it)